# How to get google trace to visually indicate spans with errors

Tags: google-cloud-trace

Some spans reported to google trace represent method calls that ended in an error.
Is there a way to get google trace to visually set these spans apart from success spans (a different color, an error icon similar to AWS xray...)?

I tried setting these attributes, but visually they made no difference:

- Span status
- /error/message attribute
- /error/name attribute
- /http/status_code attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [Trace Filter](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/trace-filters). This will filter the Traces by “Terms”. For instance, you could select the span as well as a latency and Stackdriver Trace will filter it.